# Binding function to rvalue reference

Tags: c++

How come the following works?

```
double doubleVal(double val) {
    return val*2;
}

int main()
{
    double myVal = 3.0;
    double(*&&ptr)(double) = &doubleVal; // Why?
}
```

I don't understand why the function address can be converted to an rvalue reference.. isn't it an lvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically asking why:

```
using T = ...;
T someVal;

T*&& ref = &someVal;
```

works. While `someVal` is an lvalue, `&someVal` is a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue_.28until_C.2B.2B11.29_.2F_prvalue_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29), which is a kind of rvalue. Any rvalue may be used to initialize an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler recognizes the syntax as being a function pointer

```
double(*ptr)(double) = &doubleVal;
```

The additional `&&` is applied against ptr, not the properties of the function to which ptr will point

```
double(*&&ptr)(double) = &doubleVal;
```

accepts *a reference to an rvalue*, and the thing on the right *is* an rvalue - it doesn't have a name or an address until it is stored in `ptr`.

```
return &(&doubleVal); // warning - returning address of temporary
```